# iPhone battery life: Siri or iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, battery, siri, ios

I updated my iPhone 4S to iOS 6. I suddenly activated Siri (because finally it comes in my language) and in this days I noticed that my iPhone battery life is less than previously.

This problem is due to iOS 6 (that maybe needs more power) or it is due to Siri? I have to say that I didn't used Siri in this days. So Siri consume battery even if I don't use it?

Comment: Siri doesn't consume power if it is not in use.

Comment: @patrix So iOS 6 consume more than iOS 5?

Comment: The last x.0 all tended to use more power, something which Apple fixed rather fast usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battery life in iOS 6 has been improved over iOS5 - the big thing will be Siri.

Siri listens to your voice and then sends that information to Apple's servers, which sends it back to your phone. All this costs data and the use of the hardware to accomodate that.

So even thought the battery life has been improved, because you use more features that require more intense processing, you will find that your battery may reduce. In my case I find that I do not use bluetooth as much, so I turn it off when I do not use it.

Hope this helps:-)